# Select specific sibling element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In my app I want to get sibling elements of the task-update element, when it is clicked, and then change their classes.

HTML:

```
<template id="template-task">
    <li>
        <span id="task-title"></span>
        <input id="task-title-input" class="hide">
        <span id="task-text"></span>
        <input id="task-text-input" class="hide">
        <span id="task-update">Update</span>
        <span id="task-save" class="hide">Save</span>
        <span id="task-del">Delete</span>

    </li>
</template>
```

JS:

```
this.closest("#task-text").classList.add("hide");
this.closest("#task-text-input").classList.remove("hide");
this.closest("#task-title").classList.add("hide");
this.closest("#task-title-input").classList.remove("hide");
this.closest("#task-save").classList.remove("hide");
```

This solution sadly doesn't work for me. From what I read it's because `closest` looks only for parent elements. Is there another way to do it? Selecting these items with `nextSibling`, `prevSibling` doesn't look well to me.

Comment: since the items all have an ID, why not just use `document.getElementByID`? (Assuming you don't duplicate these IDs elsewhere in your page of course - but if you do, that's the first problem you need to fix!)

Comment: `this.closest("li").querySelector("#task-text").classList.add("hide");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the parent node you then can access its children.

Comment: Ohh, yea. Completlty blanked out out about this possibility. Thanks